# Is there a way to make a bootable Linux live USB disk from a Linux docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a Linux docker container. I can kind of ssh into it, running it like a little Linux system. Can I put this on a USB disk somehow, along with a bootloader of some sort, and boot up directly to the docker container? (While keeping it as a docker container, that is.)

Comment: Running the container image as a USB stick shouldn't be too hard. Running the container on a USB stick should be ok too.  "boot up directly to the docker container while keeping it as a container" might not be, depends what you mean by that?

Comment: This is probably a question for [unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Cool. How do you run the container image on live USB disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker itself doesn't include boot loaders, a kernel, or init. The easiest way to implement this if you really want to use a Docker image is to use another usb bootable Linux distro where you've installed Docker and loaded your image.

Distributions that focus on Docker, though not necessarily booting from USB, include boot2docker and CoreOS. However these are designed to be managed as a Docker host and would require extra work to turn them into something like a kiosk mode that attaches directly to the container on startup.

Outside of Docker, you can take a usb bootable Linux distro and rerun all the commands from your Dockerfile's, including those from the parent Dockerfile. Start from the same base distribution. You will lose the immutability of the image, but remove any of the complexity needed to attach directly to the container on startup.